# How come when it rusts iron can undergo oxidation without the prescence of a another metal to undergo reduction?

Tags: electrochemistry, corrosion

It seems to me rusting is an electrochemical process where oxygen, which has particularly high electronegativity, fills the role of cathode or is that an incorrect way to put it?

Comment: The main problem you're having is that electrochemical processes don't have to have a cathode/anode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rusting is a redox reaction.
$\ce{4 Fe + 3 O2 -> 2 Fe2O3}$

Redox reactions mean one chemical is being reduced and one is being oxidized. Reduction = electron gain, oxidation = electron loss. The *reason* it is called oxidation is because oxygen is so good at reducing other chemicals (it wants electrons). How do you tell what gets electrons in a compound? Oxidation numbers.

Oxidation numbers signify how many electrons each atom has. -n means it has n more than neutral state, +n means it has n less than neutral state. In molecules which have only one element, oxidation state is 0. So Fe/O2 both have oxidation state 0. There are some rules on oxidation states in compounds which are complicated, basically usually group 1 is +1, group 2 is +2, O is -2, and group 17 is -1. In this case each O in the end is -2, and Fe is +3. So each Fe lost 3 electrons.

Comment: Some rules: https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-calculate-the-oxidation-number-of-an-element-in-a-compound